# Is it possible to install multiple version packages when installing Ubuntu apt mirror?

Tags: apt-mirror

You are about to install apt mirror for Ubuntu 20,22 OS version.

Can I install apt-mirror for the above two OS versions on one physical server?

For example, after installing version 22 OS on a server, you can install apt-mirror, and you can install apt-mirror for version 20, which is a subversion.

Comment: There is not version "Ubuntu 20" or "Ubuntu 22". All Ubuntu relase have a 4-digit version number like e.g. 23.04. Please edit your question and state which Ubuntu releases you really use.

Comment: `apt-mirror` itself doesn't depend on the version of the current OS. You can have it mirror the repos for any version.